# Moving jar to libs folder in eclipse

Tags: android, adt

Following the new ADT 17, I'm trying to move an imported jar file from "Referenced libraries" to "libs".
 It seems like I'm doing something wrong. I created a new (regular) folder and named it "libs". When I'm trying to drag/copy paste the jar, it says "Cannot paste the clipboard contents into the selected elements". 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as an idea. Don't use Eclipse to copy the files. Copy them with our file browser. After you are done goto Eclipse, click at the project's root and press F5.