# Scribe Library Error : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to use the Scribe library to practice creating apps that use OAuth.
However when I try to build my app I get the following error :

```
06-18 12:11:49.336: E/dalvikvm(4800): Could not find class'org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder', referenced from method lite.hattrick.main.LoginActivity.onCreate
06-18 12:11:49.336: W/dalvikvm(4800): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 783 (Lorg/scribe/builder/ServiceBuilder;) in Llite/hattrick/main/LoginActivity;
06-18 12:11:49.336: D/dalvikvm(4800): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0018
06-18 12:11:49.336: E/dalvikvm(4800): Could not find class 'org.scribe.model.Verifier', referenced from method lite.hattrick.main.LoginActivity.onResume
06-18 12:11:49.336: W/dalvikvm(4800): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 790 (Lorg/scribe/model/Verifier;) in Llite/hattrick/main/LoginActivity;
06-18 12:11:49.336: D/dalvikvm(4800): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0029
06-18 12:11:49.336: D/dalvikvm(4800): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x18d4 at 0x1a in Llite/hattrick/main/LoginActivity;.onCreate
06-18 12:11:49.336: D/dalvikvm(4800): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x18e2 at 0x31 in Llite/hattrick/main/LoginActivity;.onResume
06-18 12:11:49.336: I/dalvikvm(4800): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0ca6 at 0xcc in Llite/hattrick/main/LoginActivity;.onResume
06-18 12:11:49.346: D/dalvikvm(4800): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x18dc at 0xd0 in Llite/hattrick/main/LoginActivity;.onResume
06-18 12:11:49.456: D/AndroidRuntime(4800): Shutting down VM
06-18 12:11:49.456: W/dalvikvm(4800): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a75228)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at lite.hattrick.main.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:45)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5005)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-18 12:11:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I really have no clue as to what I'm doing wrong. I added the libraries as instructed on [this](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started) site by downloading the commons-codec and the scribe-1.3.0 jars. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

All library files must be placed in a directory called `libs` that is on the same level as `src` and `assets` and `res`.

Create that directory, drop the .jar files in there and Eclipse will take care of the rest.  You don't need to worry about adding them to the build path or anything else.

Comment: I did that. It had no effect.

Comment: Did you remove the jar from the project first?  Did you copy them in via Eclipse or a file browser?  That seems to have been an issue for someone else per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067227/1105376).  Did you try cleaning your project?